# How to add one to he last value in a list Python

Tags: python-3.x

Im fairly new to python and want to know how to add one to the last value in a list such as [1,5,9] or [44,45,20] I know it needs a for loop somewhere but how?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this `my_list[-1] += 1` .

the negative index let you start from the ending of a list (or any other iterable object), so -1 index is the last element in your list.

Answer (score 2):

If by "adding" you mean arithmetic addition (i.e. `+`), do:

```
mylist[-1] += 1
```

If by "adding" you mean *appending* a new item to the list, do:

```
mylist.append(1)
```

Comment: Yeah i dont want to append anything to the end, just a list like [1,5,9] turns into [1,5,10]